# directive ng-click doesnt call the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
angular.module('havuraApp').directive('userCard', function () {
    'use strict';

    var controller = function ($scope) {

        $scope.clearCard = function (btn) {
            alert('clearCard was called');
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'components/userCard/userCard.tpl.html',
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'userCardController'
    };
```

my template, has the following code:

```
<button class="btn btn-simple" ng-click="userCardController.clearCard(this)">
                            <i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Clear
                        </button>
```

I get an error: clearCard is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call it without referencing your controller first (userCardController.clearCard()) as the function is on the $scope, not 'this'

```
<button class="btn btn-simple" ng-click="clearCard()">
    <i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i> Clear
</button>
```

Comment: I apologize, I do have ng-click and still getting the same error

Comment: Also notice how it should be ng-click="clearCard()", not ng-click="userCardController.clearCard()"

Comment: As the question has been edited, the beginning of this answer does not make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `controllerAs` syntax, but then you have defined the click handler on the `$scope`.

When you use `controllerAs` it is intended that you define the functions on your controller object itself, not the `$scope`.

```
var controller = function ($scope) {
    this.clearCard = function (btn) {
        alert('clearCard was called');
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you can do what @Kevin F suggested in the comment to his answer. I didn't notice that earlier. The point is either use the `controllerAs` version of the syntax or not. If you follow his suggestion, you should also remove the `controllerAs` from your directive.